# How to convert time to percentage? (Description inside)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm doing one daily working shedule project windows phone. In that initially I'll set the maximum hour or minutes to a variable, assume i.e., 100%. if the time decreases then the percentage should also decrease.

for example assume we give 10hours for 100%, if the hours reduced to 5 the percentage should be 50%.

somebody tell me how to do this.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: You described the process well, what's the problem? Just implement it.

Comment: -1 for this is very basic math. [Hint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28mathematics%29#Rule_of_Three)

Comment: If you have problems of this level, you should really consider taking a math class. I mean, a 5th grade elementary school math class. There is no such thing as too late. BTW the answer for `somebody tell me how to do this` is: start coding, and don't stop till its done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple function should suffice.Do you can try this please ?

```
    //Example initial time to 1 houre == 100%
    TimeSpan InitialTime = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

    private double getPercentOnTime(TimeSpan currentTime,TimeSpan timeToRemove)
    {

        //Convert all to minutes
        double currentTime_minute = currentTime.TotalMinutes;
        double timeToRemove_minute = timeToRemove.TotalMinutes;
        double InitialTime_minute = InitialTime.TotalMinutes;

        //Calcul the additional time to remove from InitialTime
        double totaltimeToRemove = currentTime_minute + timeToRemove_minute;

        //calcul the new percent
        double percent = (InitialTime_minute / 100.0) * totaltimeToRemove;

        return percent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan totalTime;
TimeSpan actualTime

actualTime.TotalMiliseconds / totalTime.TotalMiliseconds * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Somtehing like that:

```
var tenHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(10); // 100%
var testHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(3); // 30%
var percent = ((float) testHours.Ticks/tenHours.Ticks)*100f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format a `double` value (0.0 - 1.0) as a percentage using the ["P" formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

```
(0.5).ToString("P0"); // "50%"
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess it's because the question wasn't about formatting, but about computing percentage. Your answer assumes the OP already knows how to compute (which he apparently doesn't). I'm upvoting, because I never knew about the `double.ToString(string format)`

Answer (score 0):

Simple proportion. if 10 hours is 100% 5 hours is how much...
5/10*100